Average case run time of a randomly distributed variable
If we have a variable with some distribution, m. And we have an array that grows by the variable m, and will grow to size n, how does one calculate the computational complexity?
Like....worst case would be if m has no distribution and then the runtime would be:
n * (1/m + 2/m .... + 1) = O(nm/2) or O(nm)
I suppose best case could be a geometric series like
n* (1/2^0 + 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8) which is equal to O(n).
but if m is a random variable, and then we sort the array of m from smallest to largest, so that the array that will grow to size n will stay as small as possible for as long as possible, how would we calculate the total run time?
Does anyone know where I would start to derive this? Or if there's a textbook that has the answers to this. It feels like this should be a common problem, where the amount of operations will grow per iteration, but the overall runtime/computational complexity depends on the growth rate.
I've tried to calculate this with a gaussian distribution for m, but I'm stuck. I also tried the above described distributions but those are trivial cases.
